# i'm making an 2 bit Arithmetic logic unit in VHDL.Its giving an type error

Tags: vhdl

```
entity alu is
        Port ( a,b,Sel : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
               res : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0));
end alu;
architecture Behavioral of alu is
begin
process(Sel,a,b)
begin
case Sel is
when "00" =>
    res<=a+b;
when "01" =>
    res<=a+(not b)+1;
when "10" =>
    res<=a and b;
when "11" =>
    res<=a or b;
when others =>
    res<="xx";
end case;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

My file name is alu.vhd
However running this gives me an error:
*Type of res is incompatible with type of xx*
in line 4.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a vital part of your entity structure:

```
architecture Behavioral of alu is
begin
  case Sel is
    -- ...
  end case;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Where is the start of the process? It needs to look like:

```
architecture Behavioral of alu is
begin
  process (Sel, a, b)  -- process definition and sensitivity list
  begin
    case Sel is
      -- ...
    end case;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Per the comment, you also have a duplicate case.

Lastly, your assignment to `"xx"` needs to use a capital letter, i.e.  `"XX"`. However, since you will have covered all the valid states for `Sel` once you correct the duplicate, you might more conventionally complete your `others` clause like so:

```
when others =>
  NULL;
```

This means 'do nothing' for other cases.

Comment: Thanks i corrected,but now it shows error in Line 17:  _Type of res is incompatible with type of xx_